# How to export listbox or datagridview to a pdf file?

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

```
Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream("AverageScore.pdf", FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();
        document.Add(new Paragraph(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()));
        document.Close();
```

I try to use this way but I dont know how I can add in this line:

```
document.Add(new Paragraph(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()));
```

Thanks so much for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have an example to convert information in a webgrid to a PDF, passing it to XHTML, then exporting it to PDF by ITextSharp. I tested it and it works...

```
//Code to Export data to PDF file
            public FileStreamResult ExportPdf()
            {
                List data = new List();
                using (DatabaseEntities db = new DatabaseEntities())
                {
                    data = db.UserTables.ToList();
                }
                //convert all webgrid data to single string
                WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: data, canSort: false, canPage: false);
                string griddata = grid.GetHtml(
                        columns: grid.Columns(
                            grid.Column("UserID", "UserID"),
                            grid.Column("UserName", "User Name"),
                            grid.Column("Address", "Address"),
                            grid.Column("PostalCode", "Postal Code"),
                            grid.Column("Phone", "Phone")
                       )
                    ).ToString();
                //display styles for webgrid table in pdf sheet
                //because iTextSharp takes XHTML and css to pdf.so we need to pass data in XHTML format 
                string export = String.Format(""<html><head>{0}</head><body>{1}</body></html>", "<style>table{ border-spacing: 10px; border-collapse: separate;}</style>", griddata);
                //converting all data into bytes in UTF-8 format
                var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(export);
                //Now prepare docment using iTextsharp module
                //And print using PDF writer
                using (var input = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                {
                    var output = new MemoryStream();
                    var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 50, 50);
                    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);
                    writer.CloseStream = false;
                    document.Open();

                var XmlWorker = iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
                XmlWorker.ParseXHtml(writer, document, input, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                document.Close();
                output.Position = 0;
                return new FileStreamResult(output, "application/pdf");
```

PD: http://www.mitechdev.com/2016/07/Export-web-grid-to-pdf-in-mvc5.html

Answer (score 0):

I wish I had more information but this is a link I came across that uses PdfWriter. Not sure which version but the link is here... http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/csharp-pdf-list-combobox.htm

As for some code... looks like this is where it happens....

```
//multiple selection listbox
TextField mlistbox = new TextField(writer, new Rectangle(36, 690, 150, 740), "mlistbox");
mlistbox.Choices = languages;
mlistbox.ChoiceExports = exports;
mlistbox.Options = TextField.MULTISELECT;
List<int> selections=new List<int>();
selections.Add(0);
selections.Add(2);
mlistbox.ChoiceSelections=selections;
```

HTH